# Building test project in Cocos2dx ( libgnustl_static.a: Permission denied )

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am starting with `cocos2dx`.
Having setup the environment on Windows 8, I created a new project using `create-android-project.bat`.

Now when I build the project by using `./build_native.sh` in `cygwin`, I get the following errors:

```
c:/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ./obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-binary.mk:378: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi/libgame.so' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgame.so] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4/test/proj.android'
```

I figured that as it was a `permission denied` error, so I tried `chmod 777 -R` on both the `cocos2dx` directory and the `NDK` directory, but to no avail.

I can't figure out what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

With NDK r8b, you don't need cygwin. Take cygwin/bin off the PATH and run ndk-build.cmd.

BTW, I strongly recommend to upgrade to NDK r9b. It's free.

Comment: The problem was fixed, all it needed was cleaning. I had to do `./build_native.sh clean` before building it again. 

And about upgrading to r9b, I cannot, because I have to continue onto a old project which uses r8b.

Anyway Thanks!

Comment: And yes, before cleaning, I also needed to do `chmod` for both the `NDK` directory and also the `cocos2dx` directory.